# How to prevent mouse enter/leave to occur too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code that basically says: if you roll over this , then the other thing appears and if you roll out then it will disappear.

The problem is that if I take the mouse and roll over/out too many times then the elements appears/disappears too many times (because I have created a lot of events for it by mistake)

my code looks like this:

```
$('div.accordionContent').mouseenter(function()
{
    $(this).find(".something").animate({left: 0}, 300)}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".something").animate({
    left: -200}, 500);;
});
```

How do I tell it to avoid multiple hovering?

I use jQuery 1.4.3 if that helps..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than avoiding multiple triggering, try stopping the animation before starting another.

```
$('div.accordionContent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".something").stop().animate(...)
});
```

Comment: good option! even i have implemented the the same in my code.

Comment: In my case, I'm not using animation (just adding/removing classname) and hence can't use `stop`. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you fire new events before the old ones have finished. To prevent this you could stop listening (remove the listeners) for future events until the current events have finished their tasks.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has an option "queue". If you set that to `false`, I think the event won't trigger as much. I think =)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it the correct way, i suggest this

```
$('div.accordionContent').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){

    var $something = $(this).find(".something");

    if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
        $something.animate({left:0}, {queue:false, duration:300 });
    } else {
        $something.animate({left:-200}, {queue:false, duration:500 });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$('div.accordionContent').mouseenter(function(){
    var div = $(this);
    clearTimeout(window.me);
    window.me = setTimeout(function(){
        div.find(".something").animate({left: 0}, 300)}).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find(".something").animate({
            left: -200}, 500); 
        });
    },50);
});
```

The idea here is to cancel the current mouseenter if the 50 delay isn't reached yet.